# conda: why I can not install pkgs in one environment, while I can install in another?

Tags: anaconda

I'm using two environment of conda. I can not intall packages in one env, while I can intall packages in the other environment.
The error massage is: 'solving environment: failed'

system: windows 10 x64

The error msg:

```
(py3env) C:\>conda install cython
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64::protobuf==3.2.0=py36_0 -> libprotobuf==3.2.0
  - anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64::tensorflow==1.2.1=py36_0 -> backports.weakref==1.0rc1
  - anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64::tensorflow==1.2.1=py36_0 -> bleach==1.5.0
  - anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64::tensorflow==1.2.1=py36_0 -> html5lib==0.9999999

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

While the success info in another environment:

```
(py2env) C:\>conda install cython Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\envs\py2env

  added / updated specs:
    - cython


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    certifi-2019.6.16          |           py27_0         151 KB
    cython-0.29.11             |   py27hc56fc5f_0         2.0 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         2.1 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cython             pkgs/main/win-64::cython-0.29.11-py27hc56fc5f_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  certifi            anaconda/pkgs/free::certifi-2016.2.28~ --> pkgs/main::certifi-2019.6.16-py27_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: The problem dependencies appear to be libraries that are unrelated to the Cython installation but are present in that environment. Can you create a new Python 3 environment and try to install Cython? What is the output of `conda list` for both environments? This is definitely related to https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/

Comment: @darthbith, I created a new env(py3.7) and everthing works well. Not only Cython, any package installation will be failed in 'py3env' but works in other environments. The output of `conda list` for either environments looks normal, i.e. listing the packages installed in each env. Could it be because I installed keras in the 'py3env'?

Comment: I think it is because you have packages installed from the "free" channel, but that channel has been removed. So conda is confused about what to do. You should read the blog post I linked to and temporarily add the "free" channel back to your configuration as described in that post.

Comment: @darthbith, The problem is solved by reading your link of blog and run the command `conda config --set restore_free_channel true`. Thank you very much!! After I ran that command, i set the restore free channel back to `false` when i finished installing the `Cython`. Then, when I try to install other pkgs, everything looks normal. No error any more.

Comment: Awesome, feel free to write an answer below with the steps you took! I'm glad it worked out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you have packages installed from the "free" channel, but that channel has been removed. So conda is confused about what to do. You should read the blog post [anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/) and temporarily add the "free" channel back to your configuration as described in that blog by running the command `conda config --set restore_free_channel true`. After you run that command, you can set the restore free channel back to `false` if you finished installing the Cython. Thanks for the comments of @darthbith